# error TS2339: Property 'firebaseConfig' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'

Tags: firebase, deployment, angular5

Getting this error while deploying code.

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(26,49): 
>   error TS2339: Property 'firebaseConfig' does not exist on type '{
>   production: boolean; }'.

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts/contacts.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contacts/contact/contact.component';
import { ContactListComponent } from './contacts/contact-list/contact-list.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactsComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    ContactListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone please help me.

here is my environment config 
`export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAyVk7gK3ZL8RJ1vDuMm5pwJKDTJKQZbZ0",
    authDomain: "contactlist-163b0.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://contactlist-163b0.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "contactlist-163b0",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "593204922920"
  }
};`

Answer (score 9):

You need to add your 'firebaseConfig' configuration in your 'environment.prod.ts' file as well.

Answer (score 5):

you need to add the same config firebase configuration in environment.prod.ts like so:

```
 firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAyVk7gK3ZL8RJ1vDuMm5pwJKDTJKQZbZ0",
    authDomain: "contactlist-163b0.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://contactlist-163b0.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "contactlist-163b0",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "593204922920"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your src/environments/enviorment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: 'apiKey',
    authDomain: 'authDomain',
    databaseURL: 'databaseURL',
    projectId: 'projectId',
    storageBucket: 'storageBucket',
    messagingSenderId: 'messagingSenderId',
    appId: 'appId',
    measurementId: 'measurementId'
  }
};
```

In your app.module.ts file

```
import { AngularFireModule, FirebaseOptionsToken } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

imports: [
    AngularFireModule
  ],
providers: [{ provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, useValue: environment.firebaseConfig }]
```